# Unable to access tomcat manager GUI (Tomcat9+Java9)

Tags: java, tomcat, java-9, tomcat9

I am using tomcat version 9.0.1. Running on a linux machine using java 9.

in my tomcat-users.xml i have added below

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager,manager-script"/>
```

in my server.xml added below line after googling

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

After that i started by tomcat server, while accessing the maneger gui getting below error

```
403 Access Denied

You are not authorized to view this page.
If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
```

please help

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Yes, i have added the user details in tomcat-users.xml , as mentioned in the post. and restarted, still same issue

Comment: *If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.* I meant this...Can you share the file as wel?

Comment: added the file tomcat-users.xml

Comment: The tomcat-users.xml and server.xml that come with your tomcat installation have starter examples in them that are commented out. Try starting over using those examples uncommenting the correct realm and options you need in tomcat-users. I point this out because the format for tomcat-users.xml has changed from older versions so the examples you may have googled may be off.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I tried it didn't work. in windows machine its working fine , i am facing this issue only in linux machine

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for the `403 ERROR` is adding your `IP/IPs` to the file

```
webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

in the section:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"  allow="X.X.X.X"/>
```